# display "print pdf" button on order view page in admin panel

Tags: pdf, admin-panel

In magento admin panel, on invoice view page, we can see there is "print pdf" option.

we want to display "print pdf" on order view page.

Comment: Did you try [Googling](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+order+pdf) for it? First link presents a very good solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to loop on the invoice collection of your order (even if you have just one invoice per order, Magento store a 1-* relation).

And for each invoice generate the link.

I let you theme as you want.

```
$adminHelper = Mage::helper("adminhtml");
foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
    $printInvoiceUrl = $adminHelper->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order_invoice/print', array('invoice_id' => $invoice->getId());

    //render your button
}
```

Comment: hi @pilou thanks for reply. i wanted to generate pdf for order....